# mysql delete rows in table where date of addition and modification is less than 2022

Tags: mysql

There is a table oc_product with products, you need to delete all products the date of addition and modification is younger than 2022.
Table names oc_product
Columns: date_added, date_modified

I really need help please.

```
DELETE FROM `oc_product` WHERE  WHERE 'date_added'='0000-00-00 00:00:00'

DELETE FROM `oc_product` WHERE [date_modified: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 - 0000-00-00 00:00:00]
```

Tried variations of these queries, but my knowledge is not enough.
Help me please.

Comment: Square brackets aren't used in SQL queries.

Comment: YOu could easily have googled the syntax of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` to make a less-than comparison.

Don't quote column names. See
[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks).

Compare with `2022-01-01`, not `0000-00-00`.

```
DELETE FROM oc_product
WHERE date_added < '2022-01-01' AND date_modified < '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this made it much easier to clean up the "junk goods"

Comment: This is incredibly basic syntax. You need to review your textbook/tutorials.